# Should we burninate [word-problem]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've had an issue with the [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) tag for a while. It's currently being used as a replacement or co-tag for:

- [story](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story)
- [wordplay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordplay) or [word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word)
- [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics)

Of these, only the last is what the tag should actually be used for, according to the tag wiki. However, even if it *was* only used for mathematical puzzles, there's another problem!

"Word problem" suggests the type of mathematical problem in textbooks. And as we've discussed before, [those are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic). For the ones that *are* on-topic, [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) is already a perfectly suitable tag, and [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) just talks about the *style* it's presented in - sounds dangerously close to a meta tag to me.

So we have a tag that's currently being used for three vastly different things, where it *is* valid it's unnecessary, and it only describes the presentation style rather than the actual content.

My question is this: **Should we get rid of the tag?** (If you can think of any reasons to keep it, please indicate them in an answer).

Answer (score 13):

**Yes**, we should get rid of it.
There is no reason to keep [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem).

Comment: Yep, I agree. We don't need it in the slightest

Comment: I don't see a reason to keep it either. If it happens to be a [mathematics] problem it'll be pretty evident if it's a word-problem or not.

Comment: ***BURNINATE***!

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, a less subtle way of putting it yes :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Darn it, I was trying to be subtle...  :P

Comment: Good idea. Just so long as any questions tagged [word-problem] which should have [mathematics] but don't have it, get it. Just as we don't have a tag especially for a [cipher] puzzle with a [story], we don't need one for a [mathematics] puzzle with a [story] either. [word-problem] was a poor name, anyway -- suggesting wordplay for which, as you point out, we have a tag.

Comment: I had failed to notice the mathematics requirement. I burninated the tag from all my questions that had it and replaced with either nothing or [tag:story] as that it what I usually meant.