# Before the Burnination: retagging [word-problem] questions

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

The consensus at [Should we burninate [word-problem]?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/should-we-burninate-word-problem) has been strongly (+13/-0) in favour of burninating the [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) tag. Great news, I say ... but there's still the problem of what to do with all the questions which currently bear this tag. A Stack Exchange employee can easily burninate the tag (as [previously happened](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2957/5373) with [brainteaser](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brainteaser)), removing it from all questions automatically and retagging all questions tagged *only* [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) with the placeholder tag [untagged](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), but that will make it impossible to search for all the questions which *had* the [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) tag. This is the last time we'll ever be able to get all those questions in one place, so let's tidy them up while we can!

The latter isn't going to be much of a problem: once the burnination has happened, we can easily find a list of all the [untagged](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions and retag them properly. What *could* be a problem is **the questions which are currently tagged with both [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) *and other, inappropriate, tags***.

---

The purpose of this meta post is to establish a list of all questions which satisfy the following criteria:

- they are tagged with **both [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) and other tag(s)**
- when [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) disappears, **they will be badly tagged**

I.e. never mind about the questions which will become [untagged](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged), or about those which are tagged [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) even though they're not about "*A mathematical puzzle that's stated in words, usually in terms of a story or a situation that dresses the problem up*", provided the other tags are sensible.

---

I'm going to post a community-wiki answer to this question to start off the list. Let's go through [the list of all 160-odd [word-problem] questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem?page=4&sort=newest&pagesize=50) starting from the oldest and working forwards. Everyone, please feel free to chip in, either adding to the list or crossing off questions from it as you go and fix them. But please don't get too carried away with retagging dozens of questions at once, because [unfortunately there's no way of doing so without bumping all those questions to the front page](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5487/5373).

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I previously started going through the list from the lowest-voted questions instead of the oldest, so the list below isn't in age order. Nonetheless, these are the questions I've found so far which need retagging pre-burnination:

- [Can you find my friends' birthday](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3486/can-you-find-my-friends-birthday) [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) and/or [calculation-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculation-puzzle) would be more appropriate than [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction).
- [A village of pick pockets!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8053/a-village-of-pick-pockets) Should probably be [strategy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) or [optimisation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation) rather than [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction).
- [Mysterious Murder Mystery 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5135/mysterious-murder-mystery-4) Not a [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle). The other tags are OK.
- [Longest sentence with each letter repeated n times](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/longest-sentence-with-each-letter-repeated-n-times) Should be tagged [english](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) or [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language).
- [About Grelling's Paradox](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2281/about-grellings-paradox) Not sure about this one; maybe should be [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) or [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction)?
- [A party with strange people: Who are they?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22322/a-party-with-strange-people-who-are-they) Doesn't really meet the description of the [word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) tag. Maybe [enigmatic-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle)?

I had been through all the [word-problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problem) questions which (on 18 Sep) had a score of 7 or less.

Comment: Went ahead and deleted the three posts you suggested for deletion.